# JSON_EXTRACT in BigQuery Standard SQL?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm converting some SQL code from BigQuery to BigQuery Standard SQL.

I can't seem to find JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR in Bigquery Standard SQL, is there an equivalent?

Answer (score 4):

Edit: we implemented the JSON functions a while back. You can read about them [in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#json-functions).

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of, but there is always workaround

Let's assume we want to mimic example from [JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#json_extract_scalar) documentation

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR('{"a": ["x", {"b":3}]}', '$.a[1].b') as str
```

Below code does same

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(json STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  try { var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
  } catch (e) { return null }
  return parsed.a[1].b;
""";

SELECT CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT('{"a": ["x", {"b":3}]}') AS str
```

I think this can be good starting point to experiment with
see more for [Scalar UDF in BigQuery Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/user-defined-functions)

> Quick update

After cup of coffee, decided to complete this "exercise" by myself
Look as a good short term solution to me  :o)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(json STRING, json_path STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  try { var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
  } catch (e) { return null }
  return eval(json_path.replace("$", "parsed"));
""";

SELECT 
  CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT('{"a": ["x", {"b":3}]}', '$.a[1].b') AS str1,
  CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT('{"a": ["x", {"b":3}]}', '$.a[0]') AS str2,
  CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT('{"a": 1, "b": [4, 5]}', '$.b') AS str3
```